# Kaby Lake CPU based system and MS Server 2008/2012

Tags: windows-server-2008, nvme, kaby-lake

I've been asked to provide an opinion on the spec of a Windows server, and, as a Linux person, I'm out of my depth.  The system is built around an Asus Z170-AR motherboard, Kaby Lake [ i7-7700 ] CPU, and Samsung 960 m.2 NVMe SSD's

Can anyone advise -

Without virtualisation, Can you install Windows Server 2008 (or Windows Server 2012 - the spec requires downgrade rights from 2012 to 2008 R2) on a Kaby Lake system running Z170 motherboard ?   The Z170 motherboard des not appear to have any USB2 ports.

Similarly, will the OS be able to access the NVMe based SSD ?

Comment: Actually, according to q15 at http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/D/B/4DB352D1-C610-466A-9AAF-EEF4F4CFFF27/WS2012_Licensing-Pricing_FAQ.pdf even standard edition has downgrade rights.

Comment: I suppose its good to learn something new.

Comment: Very partial answer - https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/02/use-windows-server-with-skylake-and-you-wont-have-to-upgrade-in-18-months/ implies Server 2012 may support Kaby Lake (but it won't be supported under Server 2008 ]